# How Can I Get An Enum's String Value Dynamically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, enums, activemodel

I have a `Video` model with a property called `aspect_ratio` that is an `enum`:

```
ASPECT_RATIOS = [:four_three, :sixteen_nine]

enum aspect_ratio: ASPECT_RATIOS
```

The property is stored as an integer.

When I access this property, I get a string representation of the enumerated symbol

```
video.aspect_ratio # four_three
video.aspect_ratio.class # String
```

However when I iterate over the model's properties using `video.attributes.each_pair`the value of `aspect_ratio` is an integer. I need to iterate over attributes in such a way that if the attribute is an enum I get the string value, not its integer value.

The following also return its integer value:

```
video.read_attribute(:aspect_ratio)
video[:aspect_ratio]
```

**Is there another way to iterate to ensure I get the string value of the enum?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try the easiest way: `video.public_send(:aspect_ratio)`

Comment: Was this supposed to be :aspect_ratio rather than :aspect_ration?